# shell script - while loop does not terminate

Tags: shell, while-loop

I have a while loop in shell and it does not terminate even though it has a break condition, this piece of code run well in other languages but i can't figure out how while loop runs in shell script.
Here is my code:

```
NAME=""
while [[ $NAME != "q"  || $NAME != "Q" ]]
do
    read NAME
    //do something


done
```

Comment: NAME is always not "q" or not "Q". For example, "q" is not "Q"; "Q" is not "q"; and "x" is neither "q" nor "Q". You want `&&`, not `||`. (This would behave identically in other languages, the error is purely logical.)

Comment: @Amadan yes thank  you very much, code in shell looks different from others, i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$NAME != "q" || $NAME != "Q"
```

Unless `NAME` can exist in a strange " Schrödinger's cat" sort of state where it can be both `Q` and `q` *at the same time,* this expression will *always* be true.

Think about it:

- If `NAME` is *neither* `q` nor `Q`, both sub-expressions will be true so the full expression will be true.
- If it's `Q`, then the first sub-expressions will be true, leading to the full expression being true as well.
- If it's `q`, then the second sub-expressions will be true, leading to the full expression being true as well.

What you *probably* need is:

```
$NAME != "q" && $NAME != "Q"
```

Of course, if it's `bash` that you're using, it provides a way to uppercase and lowercase a string to make these comparisons easier:

```
while [[ "${NAME^^}" != "Q" ]] ; # upper-case variant
while [[ "${NAME,,}" != "q" ]] ; # lower-case variant
```

Comment: Or you could use `[[ $NAME != [Qq] ]]`